# ajaxfileupload querystring missing asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using the Ajaxfileupload to upload files and store it in the DB.

The record is coming from an Id specificed in the querystring.

```
(page.aspx?ID=10)
```

Unfortunately when the UploadComplete even fires up, it does a postback and removes my ID and use other variables.

Any Ideas how to overcome it?

I tried to pass the ID through a Form or as a Property but to no avail.

I came across this post http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27149 but I can't figure out where is the AjaxFileUpload.pre.js file and how do I override it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Oren

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this is an old question but it hasn't been answered so I will just incase you did not resolve it or it helps someone else.

You will need to download the ajaxcontroltoolkit source code at https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest# and open it in visual studio.
The file that you are looking for is at :-
Server --> AjaxControlToolkit -->AjaxFileUpload --> AjaxFileUpload.Control.pre.js

Make the changes as described in the link you gave, rebuild the solution to get an updated AjaxControlToolKit.dll file to put into your website bin folder replacing the old one.

That should solve your issues :)

Comment: i have same issue, but unable to resolve yet. Is there any other way to use querystring other than editing file? I am not getting the said file "AjaxFileUpload.Control.pre.js" from given link. :( please help me to...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203310/ajaxfileupload-control-doesnt-work-when-page-have-querystring-in-asp-net