# AjaxFileUpload control doesnt work when page have querystring in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, query-string, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I have a `button` on a `.aspx` page which opens the `popup` to `upload images` of selected item.

**ListEdit.aspx**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnListingImageUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload Images" 
                                   OnClientClick="basicPopup()"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 function basicPopup() {
             var QuoteId = document.getElementById('<%= hdnQuoteIDForListing.ClientID%>').value;
             var IsPrep = document.getElementById('<%= hdnIsPrep.ClientID%>').value;
             alert(IsPrep);
             popupWindow = window.showModalDialog('ListingImageUpload.aspx?QuoteID=' + QuoteId + '&IsPrep=' + IsPrep, 'popUpWindow', 'height=400,width=600,left=200,top=250,resizable=0');
             return false;
         }
```

**AjaxFileUpload Control on Popup Page**:

```
<cc1:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload2" ThrobberID="myThrobber" ContextKeys="fred" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete1"
```

OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadCompleteFront" />

When i `click` on `button` it opens the `page` as popup containing `AJAXFileUpload` control and `querystring` in popup page. When i click on 'Upload' button of popup page containing `AjaxFileUpload` control it gives following error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data
```

**But, when is use session instead of querystring it works fine!**

I have googled and found **[this link](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27149)** but i am not able to resolve it. I have `AJAXControlToolKit.dll` (only)in `bin folder` and not the source files and other binaries.

**NOTE:** *Please suggest solution using `querystring` only. Reason is, multiple instances of this popup will open at time. So, cant use `Session` variables.*

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can decompile de .dll with some App like Telerik, and then apply changes on the code and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, when AjaxFileUpload post back it takes your page URL and appends onto the end of it it's own.query strings (contextkey and guid). This works fine if your page URL doesn't already contain any query strings but
if it does then you end up with a URL that contains two question marks which will corrupt your final query string value and this in turn stops the upload from working.

Check this [Known Issue](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27467)